# Storing Node.JS files Within a Meteor.JS Project

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have a meteor.js project directory (created from `meteor create projectName`) and I have some regular node.js `.js` files related to this site that only needs to be run using `node fileName.js` or using `forver`.

Is there a way to store these `.js` files within the Meteor project directory without it being auto-run (like how it will be executed if placed in the `/server` directory)?

And is it more advisable to place these `.js` files outside of the Meteor project directory?

Comment: Yes you can simply put them in your `/private` folder, but what's the point of adding them to the project if you don't want them to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the meteor documentation, you could probably use the private folder.  This should stop auto-execution as well.

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp

> private: All files inside a top-level directory called private are only accessible from server code and can be loaded via the Assets API. This can be used for private data files and any files that are in your project directory that you don't want to be accessible from the outside.